# How to understand the macro of "__xg"?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

the codes:

```
struct __xchg_dummy { unsigned long a[100]; };
#define __xg(x) ((struct __xchg_dummy *)(x))
```

I'm confused with "unsigned long a[100]".So ,how to understand this macro?

Comment: You do know about structures? It's just a normal structure member variable declaration.

Comment: Looks like it's possibly used as some sort of optimization hack?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen hi what 's of "optimization hack"?

Comment: Basically, it has no effect on normal execution because it's still just a pointer. GCC, however, may take into consideration the size of what it points to when optimizing code around it - this includes making sure any local variables currently in registers are actually stored in memory before the instruction, since a common optimization technique is to reduce how often values are written to memory.

Answer (score 0):

`__xg` returns `x` address after typecasting to `struct __xchg_dummy *`. Here `struct __xchg_dummy { unsigned long a[100]; };` is a structure with an array unsigned long integers  of size 100.